# Featured image size in column

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have a featured image preview in column view in my Custom Post Types. Now I want to change the size of it. This is my code:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_img_column');
add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 'manage_img_column', 10, 2);

function add_img_column($columns) {
    $columns['img'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $columns;
}

function manage_img_column($column_name, $post_id) {
    if( $column_name == 'img' ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I see it like this:

[image]

So know I want to change the size of this image in this view... how... how can I get that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functions.php :
Make sure featured images are enabled

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

then add

```
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-news', '100', '75', true );
```

And in the code above change

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
```

to

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail-news');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new size with the funcion `add_image_size`, example:

```
add_image_size('my_new_size', 50, 50, true);
```

an then when you get the post thumbnail you select this size, like this:

```
function manage_img_column($column_name, $post_id) {
    if( $column_name == 'img' ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'my_new_size');
        return true;
    }
}
```

See the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) for reference.